# Pandas boolean index with NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this toy example which capture my real problem:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['car there is','car not working', 'bus there is']})
df.iloc[1] = np.nan
idx = df['A'].str.contains('car')
df['IsCar'] = 0
df.loc[idx,'IsCar'] = 1
```

When I try to run this code, I got the following error message:

```
ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values
```

Why can I not do this. Is there fix where I not have to replace the NaN with something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a flag `na` for `str.contains` ([*see docs*](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.0/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html)) which you can set to False, which will provide a fill value for missing values. Simply use

```
idx = df['A'].str.contains('car', na=False)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I am starting to learn Pandas and find missing values somewhat troublesome. I do got the same problem if I want to use apply on a column which contains NaN. df.A.apply(lambda x: 1 if re.search('car',x) else 0). I there anyway to get apply to skip if Nan?

Comment: I would take a look over [working with missing data](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html), glad I could help.